# ¿Llamada a metodo de varias formas? c++

Tags: c++, class

mi pregunta es si se puede hacer un metodo que no sea constructor, que pueda dar opciones a diversas formas de llamarlo, es decir, poder llamarlo sin introducir nada y que le de valores automaticos, o introducir solo uno de ellos y que el otro lo ponga fijo.
¿Y si fuera un tipo bool tambien, como seria? Muchas gracias

```
Class Persona{

  private:

  int edad;
  string nombre;

  public:

  Persona(int i,string n);
  void fulano (int i=20,string n="Alberto");



  };


 Persona::Persona (int i,string n){
 
  edad=i;
  nombre=n;

  }

  void Persona::fulano(int i=20,n="Alberto"){

  edad=i;
  nombre=n;



   }
```

¿Se podria llamar a este metodo asi?

```
Persona p;
p.fulano(); // ¿Aqui tendria p i=20 y n=Alberto?
p.fulano(5); // ¿Aqui tendria p i=5 y n=Alberto?
p.fulano(10,"Oscar"); // ¿Aqui tendria i=10 y n=Oscar?
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si se puede, se conoce como sobrecarga, y es tal como lo ejemplificas en tu segundo código. Donde sobrecargas el metodo y puedes llamarlo de diferentes formas, según se requiera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si puedes,esto se llama: **Sobrecarga de metodos**, lo que la sobrecarga de metodos permite hacer es tener un metodo con el mismo nombre declarado mas de una vez con distinta cantidad de parametros y/o de tipos distintos, por ejemplo:

```
    void Fulano(int edad,std::string nombre){
        this->edad = edad;
        this->nombre = nombre;
    }
    void Fulano(int edad){
        this->edad = edad;
        this->nombre = "Alberto";
    }
    void Fulano(std::string nombre){
        this->edad = 20;
        this->nombre = nombre;
    }
```

Cuando tu llames al metodo `Fulano` Dependiendo de la cantidad de parametros que pases o el tipo usara una funcion o otra, en este caso si cuando utilizas el metodo pasas como parametro la edad y el nombre usaria la primera, si pasas solo la edad usaria la segunda.

Entonces el código podria quedar asi:

```
#include <iostream>

class Persona{
  private:
    int edad;
    std::string nombre;
  public:

    Persona(){
      }
    void Fulano(int edad,std::string nombre){
        this->edad = edad;
        this->nombre = nombre;
    }
    void Fulano(int edad){
        this->edad = edad;
        this->nombre = "Alberto";
    }
    void Fulano(std::string nombre){
        this->edad = 20;
        this->nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    /*Esta funcion es para poder imprimir en pantalla los nombres,
    ya que cuando los atributos estan privados solo mediante
    otro metodo pueden ser utilizados
    */
    void get_name(){
        std::cout<<nombre<<std::endl;
    }
    
    
  };
  
int main(){ 
    Persona a;
    Persona b;
    Persona c;
    
    a.Fulano(17,"Franco");
    b.Fulano(20);
    c.Fulano("Rodrigo");
    
    a.get_name();
    b.get_name();
    c.get_name();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Franco
Alberto
Rodrigo
```

Como veo que tu en tu codigo no utilizas `this->` te dejo una pequeña explicacion de lo que hace:

Cuando utilizas `this->nombre_atributo` estas haciendo referencia al nombre de un atributo, la ventaja de usar esto es que en la declaracion y definicion de los metodos no necesitas ponerle otro nombre a los parametros como en el ejemplo de abajo:

```
void Fulano(int edad,std::string nombre){
    this->edad = edad;
    this->nombre = nombre;
```

`this->edad` hace referencia al atributo edad entonces cuando en la definicion de la funcion pongo `this->edad = edad` le estoy diciendo que al atributo `edad` le almacene el valor del parametro tambien llamado `edad`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Franco